# ERROR in CSS pop up

Tags: html, css, popup

I have create a pop up using only `CSS` and `HTML` it works fine as i need and here is code

```css
              .wrap {


                padding: 40px;


                text-align: center;


              }


              hr {


                clear: both;


                margin-top: 40px;


                margin-bottom: 40px;


                border: 0;


                border-top: 1px solid #aaaaaa;


              }


              h1 {


                font-size: 30px;


                margin-bottom: 40px;


              }


              p {


                margin-bottom: 20px;


              }


              .btn {


                background: #428bca;


                border: #357ebd solid 1px;


                border-radius: 3px;


                color: #fff;


                display: inline-block;


                font-size: 14px;


                padding: 8px 15px;


                text-decoration: none;


                text-align: center;


                min-width: 60px;


                position: relative;


                transition: color .1s ease;


              }


              .btn:hover {


                background: #357ebd;


              }


              .btn.btn-big {


                font-size: 18px;


                padding: 15px 20px;


                min-width: 100px;


              }


              .btn-close {


                color: #aaaaaa;


                font-size: 30px;


                text-decoration: none;


                position: absolute;


                right: 5px;


                top: 0;


              }


              .btn-close:hover {


                color: #919191;


              }


              .modal:before {


                content: "";


                display: none;


                background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);


                position: fixed;


                top: 0;


                left: 0;


                right: 0;


                bottom: 0;


                z-index: 10;


              }


              .modal:target:before {


                display: block;


              }


              .modal:target .modal-dialog {


                -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);


                -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);


                transform: translate(0, 0);


                top: 20%;


              }


              .modal-dialog {


                background: #fefefe;


                border: #333333 solid 1px;


                border-radius: 5px;


                margin-left: -200px;


                position: fixed;


                left: 50%;


                top: -100%;


                z-index: 11;


                width: 360px;


                -webkit-transform: translate(0, -500%);


                -ms-transform: translate(0, -500%);


                transform: translate(0, -500%);


                -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-out;


                -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s ease-out;


                -o-transition: -o-transform 0.3s ease-out;


                transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;


              }


              .modal-body {


                padding: 20px;


              }


              .modal-header,


              .modal-footer {


                padding: 10px 20px;


              }


              .modal-header {


                border-bottom: #eeeeee solid 1px;


              }


              .modal-header h2 {


                font-size: 20px;


              }


              .modal-footer {


                border-top: #eeeeee solid 1px;


                text-align: right;


              }
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <a href="#modal-one" class="btn btn-big">pop up!</a>
</div>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="modal-one" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h2>Modal in CSS?</h2>
      <a href="#" class="btn-close" aria-hidden="true">×</a>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>One modal example here! :D</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href="#" class="btn">Nice!</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ycc7anhy/)

**My problem is** when i click pop up entire page scroll down to bottom and pop up appears
since i have lot of content in my page

i need to open pop up on same place i don't want the page to scroll down can some one help whats wrong

**NOTE** when you try with the above code you can only find scroll little bit
but in my page it scroll to bottom of page

Comment: @MiheyEgoroff i don't use jquery in my website so if you can make the above popup work with only java you welcome please post here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understand it correctly but try to add sth like that:

`body.unscrollable {
    overflow:hidden;
}`

and add class `.unscrollable` when modal is open.
It will disable scrolling on website body.

Comment: i don't understand how it will work when i click popup , popup make page scroll

Comment: OK, so try add this to your CSS: .modal:target {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}